# Infinite perfect field of characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Given a perfect field of prime characteristic $p$, is it necessarily finite? I believe there must be some counterexample. However, the only infinite field of characteristic $p$ that I know of is $\mathbb{Z}_p(t),$ which is not perfect. Any hints?

Comment: [Algebraic closure.](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Perfect_field)

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2450648/can-we-have-a-perfect-field-of-characteristic-p-with-a-non-archimedean-valuati).

Answer (score 5):

You can take, for instance, the field $\mathbb F_p(x,x^{1/p},x^{1/p^2},\ldots)$.